# How to retrieve number of tags at a certain time in the past

Tags: google-bigquery, stackexchange-api, stackexchange

I can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004445/how-to-retrieve-stackoverflow-tag-usage-count-via-stackexchange-api-call) how to get number of tags through StackExchange API. Is it possible to get number of tags at a certain time in the past?

How can I run https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&inname=java&site=stackoverflow with [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/stackoverflow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of potentially many options - for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT tag, COUNT(1) AS popular
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts`, 
    UNNEST(SPLIT(tags, '|')) AS tag
WHERE DATE(creation_date) 
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR) 
    AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
GROUP BY tag
HAVING tag LIKE '%java%'
ORDER BY popular DESC
-- LIMIT 100
```